# Sorting a column in bash by amount of occurances of words

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, cut

So I have a text being outputted that has an ip adress in one column and an http status code in the other. I wan't to sort this column by number of occurances so that

```
x.x 1
x.x 2
x.y 1
x.z 3
y.x 4
x.x 5
x.x 4
x.x 4
```

Looks like

```
y.x 4
x.x 4
x.x 4
x.x 1
x.y 1
x.x 5
x.z 3
x.x 2
```

This is for the second column of status codes, the ip adresses dont need to be sorted in any particular order

Since 4 is the most common one it should be first and then 1 and so forth.

However all that I can find is how to use `uniq` for example in order to count the occurances, thereby removing duplicates and prefixing a number to each row.

The regular `sort` command does not support this as far as i can tell as well.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `awk + sort + cut` combination:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{++freq[$2]; next} {print freq[$2] "\t" $0}' file{,} | sort -k1nr | cut -f 2-
x.x 4
x.x 4
y.x 4
x.x 1
x.y 1
x.x 2
x.x 5
x.z 3
```

**Details:**

1. `awk` command calculated frequency of 2nd field and adds it in front of record
2. `sort` command does reverse numeric sort on frequency field
3. `cut` command strips first column from final output

Comment: I love the Schwartzian Transform https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform

Answer (score 2):

With *single* GNU ***awk*** approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc" }
     { a[$2]++; b[$2][++c]=$1 }
     END{ for(i in a) for(j in b[i]) print b[i][j],i }' file
```

- `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"` - comparison of array elements, where `"@val_num_desc"` ensures that the element values, treated as numbers, are ordered from high to low

---

The output:

```
y.x 4
x.x 4
x.x 4
x.y 1
x.x 1
x.x 2
x.z 3
x.x 5
```